# How to detect whether fonts in NSAttributedString are system fonts

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

There is an extension function used to detect whether fonts in the NSAttributedString are system fonts:

```
extension NSAttributedString
{
    func isSystemFont(at: Int) -> Bool
    {
        guard let font = self.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, at: at, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIFont else
        {
            print(font.fontName) // PingFangSC
        }
    }
}
```

### What I want?

I want this function can return whether ‘regularSystemFont’ or not, instead of ‘boldSystemFont’ or ‘blackSystemFont’, so “family name” identification is no use.

### What I did?

So I intend to compare `font.fontName` with `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName`
But `font.fontName` has returned `PingFangSC-Regular` in runtime, and `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10).fontName` has returned `.SFUI-Regular` , so it’s no use in this way.

Comment: What do you mean "it's no use"? You got the right answer. PingFangSC-Regular is not the system font. — However, you should not use _names_ to determine this in any case. The name of the system font is subject to change. And what exactly is this function for? I don't understand how you can fail to _know_ whether this font is the system font, because you must have configured it in the first place.

Comment: @matt PingFangSC-Regular is the system font in my region, but it can not to determine whether the font is system font. As you said, the name of the system font is subject to change. But I just wish this function can identify the font is system font or not. Do you have another way?